# Rendering Partial Views in a Loop in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have a pretty simple scenario, Model for my view is a List.

Loop through List like

```
@foreach(CustomObject obj in Model)
{
Html.Partial("_TrackingCustomObject",obj)
}
```

So i was expecting to have number of partial views according to my list.

Partial View has been developed accordingly.

There is no error on page. It just does not show any data that is supposed to display by partial views.

What is the reason of not showing any data?

Answer (score 11):

You are missing an @:

```
@foreach(CustomObject obj in Model)
{
    @Html.Partial("_TrackingCustomObject", obj)
}
```

But why writing foreach loops when you can use editor/display templates? Like this:

```
@model IEnumerable<CustomObject>
@Html.EditorForModel()
```

and then simply define the corresponding editor template (`~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/CustomObject.cshtml`) that will automatically be rendered for each element of your model:

```
@model CustomObject
<div>
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Foo)
</div>
```

Simple and conventional :-)

Comment: No thats not an issue as i am using razor view i don't need to put @everywhere. Still upon changing it also not works

Comment: If this doesn't work, then I suspect that your problem is somewhere else. You may start looking at your `_TrackingCustomObject.cshtml` partial for example.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**:

```
@Html.RenderPartial("_TrackingCustomObject",obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the Razor symbol `@`:

```
@foreach(CustomObject obj in Model)
{
    @Html.Partial("_TrackingCustomObject",obj)
}
```

Also **make sure** your partial view is using the object type `CustomObject` as the Model.

```
@model MyProject.Models.CustomObject

<h1>Yeah we're in a partial! @Model.SomeProperty </h1>
```

---

To try and drill down to where the error is, try placing some static text inside the PartialView.

```
<p>Some text</p>
```

If your collection has 10 items, then you should see 10 of these paragraphs. Next once this works, focus on displaying some property in each item.

```
@model MyProject.Models.CustomObject

<p>Some text</p>
<p>@Model.SomeProperty</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are creating html form using `@Html.BeginForm()` you have to wrap the remaining stuf inside a `<div>` or other container else the html elements won't get rendered.

Ex.

**this won't work**

```
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
  Html.EditorFor(m => m.Name)
}
```

**this will work**

```
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
   <div>    
      @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Name)
   </div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bit late in the day, but this worked for me in MVC 4:

```
 @foreach (var p in @Model.RelatedCards)
    {
        Html.RenderPartial("_ThumbPartial", p);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

This is too old but someone can use it.

```
@foreach(CustomObject obj in Model)
{
    <text>
        Html.Partial("_TrackingCustomObject",obj)
    </text>
}
```